# Unable to create a new organization in Hybris using Wizard

Tags: e-commerce, organization, sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

I am trying to create an organization in Hybris. I am trying to do this via the 'Create Organization Wizard' in the Admin Cockpit.
The documentation says that a pre-requisite for this is that a user in 'Account manager' Role should have been created already. My first problem is how to create such a user?
Next, if I just try to fill in some details for an Account Mgr role, then I get the below error on clicking 'Done' at the completion of wizard:

```
>> 

     at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.Wizard.doDone(Wizard.java:526)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.GenericItemWizard.doDone(G
enericItemWizard.java:680)
>>      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor934.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80)
>>      at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858)
>>      at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.bsh.BSHInterpreter.exec(BSHInterpreter.java:11
9)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.util.GenericInterpreter.interpret(GenericInter
preter.java:310)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl.interpret(PageImpl.java:797)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:176)

>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:141)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessi
ngThreadImpl.java:519)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThr
eadImpl.java:446)

Nov 04, 2016 4:27:30 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.HybrisUiEngineImpl handleError:1616

SEVERE: >>java.lang.NullPointerException
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:50)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:1)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.attribute.impl.Default
DynamicAttributesProvider.set(DefaultDynamicAttributesProvider.java:64)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.setDynamic
Value(ItemModelContextImpl.java:341)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.CustomerModel.setTickets(CustomerM
odel.java:266)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils
.java:203)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.invokeMethod(ItemModelConverter.java:1289)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.setAttributeValue(ItemModelConverter.java:1179)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelServi
ce.setAttributeValue(DefaultModelService.java:836)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.setModelSingleValue(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.ja
va:405)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.validate(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.java:205)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.Wizard.doDone(Wizard.java:526)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.GenericItemWizard.doDone(G
enericItemWizard.java:680)
>>      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor934.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80)
>>      at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858)
>>      at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.bsh.BSHInterpreter.exec(BSHInterpreter.java:11
9)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.util.GenericInterpreter.interpret(GenericInter
preter.java:310)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl.interpret(PageImpl.java:797)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:176)

>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:141)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessi
ngThreadImpl.java:519)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThr
eadImpl.java:446)

Nov 04, 2016 4:29:19 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.HybrisUiEngineImpl handleError:1616

SEVERE: >>java.lang.NullPointerException
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:50)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:1)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.attribute.impl.Default
DynamicAttributesProvider.set(DefaultDynamicAttributesProvider.java:64)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.setDynamic
Value(ItemModelContextImpl.java:341)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.CustomerModel.setTickets(CustomerM
odel.java:266)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils
.java:203)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.invokeMethod(ItemModelConverter.java:1289)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.setAttributeValue(ItemModelConverter.java:1179)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelServi
ce.setAttributeValue(DefaultModelService.java:836)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.setModelSingleValue(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.ja
va:405)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.validate(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.java:205)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.Wizard.doDone(Wizard.java:526)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.GenericItemWizard.doDone(G
enericItemWizard.java:680)
>>      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor934.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80)
>>      at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858)
>>      at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.bsh.BSHInterpreter.exec(BSHInterpreter.java:11
9)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.util.GenericInterpreter.interpret(GenericInter
preter.java:310)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl.interpret(PageImpl.java:797)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:176)

>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:141)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessi
ngThreadImpl.java:519)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThr
eadImpl.java:446)

INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
Nov 04, 2016 4:30:25 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.HybrisUiEngineImpl handleError:1616

SEVERE: >>java.lang.NullPointerException
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:50)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:1)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.attribute.impl.Default
DynamicAttributesProvider.set(DefaultDynamicAttributesProvider.java:64)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.setDynamic
Value(ItemModelContextImpl.java:341)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.CustomerModel.setTickets(CustomerM
odel.java:266)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils
.java:203)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.invokeMethod(ItemModelConverter.java:1289)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.setAttributeValue(ItemModelConverter.java:1179)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelServi
ce.setAttributeValue(DefaultModelService.java:836)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.setModelSingleValue(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.ja
va:405)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.validate(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.java:205)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.Wizard.doDone(Wizard.java:526)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.GenericItemWizard.doDone(G
enericItemWizard.java:680)
>>      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor934.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80)
>>      at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858)
>>      at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.bsh.BSHInterpreter.exec(BSHInterpreter.java:11
9)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.util.GenericInterpreter.interpret(GenericInter
preter.java:310)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl.interpret(PageImpl.java:797)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:176)

>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:141)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessi
ngThreadImpl.java:519)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThr
eadImpl.java:446)

Nov 04, 2016 4:30:46 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.HybrisUiEngineImpl handleError:1616

SEVERE: >>java.lang.NullPointerException
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:50)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.ticket.model.TicketsAttributeHandler.set(TicketsAt
tributeHandler.java:1)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.attribute.impl.Default
DynamicAttributesProvider.set(DefaultDynamicAttributesProvider.java:64)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ItemModelContextImpl.setDynamic
Value(ItemModelContextImpl.java:341)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.CustomerModel.setTickets(CustomerM
odel.java:266)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils
.java:203)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.invokeMethod(ItemModelConverter.java:1289)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.converter.impl.ItemModelConv
erter.setAttributeValue(ItemModelConverter.java:1179)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.model.impl.DefaultModelServi
ce.setAttributeValue(DefaultModelService.java:836)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.setModelSingleValue(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.ja
va:405)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.DefaultGenericItemMandator
yPageController.validate(DefaultGenericItemMandatoryPageController.java:205)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.Wizard.doDone(Wizard.java:526)
>>      at de.hybris.platform.cockpit.wizards.generic.GenericItemWizard.doDone(G
enericItemWizard.java:680)
>>      at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor934.invoke(Unknown Source)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134)
>>      at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80)
>>      at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858)
>>      at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
>>      at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
>>      at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.bsh.BSHInterpreter.exec(BSHInterpreter.java:11
9)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.scripting.util.GenericInterpreter.interpret(GenericInter
preter.java:310)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl.interpret(PageImpl.java:797)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:176)

>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:141)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessi
ngThreadImpl.java:519)
>>      at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThr
eadImpl.java:446)

WARN  [Thread-52] [AbstractBrowserArea] The browser 'de.hybris.platform.cockpit.
model.browser.impl.DefaultExtendedSearchBrowserModel@5e364212' has not been mapp
ed to a content browser. Can not refresh items.
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
INFO  [Thread-52] [CollectionEditor] [Reference Collection Editor] Fire remove i
tem
WARN  [Thread-52] [AbstractBrowserArea] The browser 'de.hybris.platform.cockpit.
model.browser.impl.DefaultExtendedSearchBrowserModel@5e364212' has not been mapp
ed to a content browser. Can not refresh items.
WARN  [Thread-52] [AbstractBrowserArea] The browser 'de.hybris.platform.cockpit.
model.browser.impl.DefaultExtendedSearchBrowserModel@5e364212' has not been mapp
ed to a content browser. Can not refresh items.
```

Hence I am unable to create a new Organization. Pls provide your suggestions

Comment: What do you mean with 'organization'? Can you show us the exact point, where you want to do this. give us a screenshot.